# Parameters of a beta distribution

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

I encountered here a question about the negative parameters of a beta distribution. Below is the link for that question:
[Negative parameters of beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52824/negative-parameters-of-beta-distribution?newreg=8db38a9a7bb542a4b78fd11085f98c77)

There is a comment where the $A$ parameter  = $\frac{m(m−2m^2+m^3−v+mv)}{(m−1)v}$ , and the $B$ parameter = $\frac{m−2m^2+m^3−v+mv}{v}$

Can I ask how to arrive to this equation or at least a reference of this? I tried to expound the a and b parameters found in Wikipedia but arrived at a slightly different answer compared to the said comment (A parameter in Wikipedia should be multiplied to -1 to arrive at the same answer).

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This might be cheating, but you can let [Wolfram Alpha solve the equations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%28x%2By%29+%3D+m+and+xy%2F%28%28x%2By%29%5E2%28x%2By%2B1%29%29+%3D+v) for you.

According to Wolfram Alpha, the nontrivial answer is
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \frac{m}{v}\big(-m^2 + m - v\big) \\
\beta &=\frac{1}{v}\big(m^3 - 2 m^2 + mv + m - v\big)
\end{align*}
assuming $m \neq 0$, $v \neq 0$ and $m^3 - 2m^2 + m v + m - v\neq0$.

Here is what the equations produce on an equi-distant grid on $[0,1]^2$ for
$(m,v)$:
[image]

The equation for the variance can be written more compactly as
$$
\beta = \frac{(1-m)[m(1-m)-v]}{v} = \frac{(1-m)}{m}\alpha.
$$

---

We can ask what combinations $(m,v) \in [0,1]^2$ lead to valid parameters  for the Beta distribution. For this, we need to have $\alpha$ and $\beta > 0$. Both of these conditions are satisfied if and only if
\begin{align*}
v < m(1-m)
\end{align*}
showing that this is the only condition needed, besides $m \in (0,1)$.